# ScollTop in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm simply tring to make changes to my webpage by scrolling the page. And in this code I am trying to change the background color of a div that is fixed in page. What is wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            height: 5000px;
        }
        div{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background: red;
            position: fixed;
            top: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>

    <div></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > 500 ){
                $('div').css("background", "green");
            } else{
                $('div').css("background", "red");
            }
        }
            change();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Issue may be with `$(window)`

Comment: You're only calling `change()` once, when the top scroll position of the window is still zero. Maybe you should bind to the `scroll` event?

Answer (score 4):

i think you should call it in `.scroll()` method:

```
$(function(){

     $(window).on('scroll', function(){
         change();
     }).scroll();

});
```

or you can do shorten the code like this:

```
$(function(){

     $(window).on('scroll', change).scroll();

});
```

---

Issue in your code is that you just called your function and that point of time the `.scrollTop()` value  was `0` and it never gets updated.

so the solution is to put this function in an event of `.scroll()` the way suggested above. At every scroll it gets the new scrolltop position.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you can tune it up a little:
   $(window).on('scroll', change);
   change();

Comment: @ sneeky i was just about to post it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('div').css("background", "green");
    } else {
        $('div').css("background", "red");
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try place your change within the document.ready..
other than that it looks OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > 500 ){
            $('div').css("background", "green");
        } else{
            $('div').css("background", "red");
        }
    }

   $(document).ready(function() {
        change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: just noticing, maybe your code is working fine but you have not given a height/width to your div so it may be too small to see.. i.e. 0 px by 0px.. try giving it a style="width:50px!important; height:50px!important;"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing `$(window).scrollTop` use `$(document).scrollTop`.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
       $(document).on('scroll',function () {
             if( $(this).scrollTop() > 500 ){
            $('aside').css("background", "green");
        } else{
            $('aside').css("background", "red");
        }
       });

      $(document).scroll();
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/PBG9Z/15/

Happy Coding :)